# How can I find out if a file I created was created during the current user's logon session?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, wmi

How can I find out if a file I created was created during the current user's logon session?  Is Win32_LogonSession.LogonId truly unique per session?

EDIT:
i'm writing the file and plan to write the logonid to the file as an identifier.  sorry that wasnt clear before.  i've been looking around but my win32 knowledge still isn't quite where it should be -- how do i find the logonsession of the user running the current process?

i just need to find SOME unique identifier for the session that i can use later to see if a file was created during the current session or another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LogonId is a LUID: It's a 64-bit number. It's guaranteed to be unique between two reboots, but a restart of the OS effectively resets the pool of possible values.

I don't think you can use it for the stated purpose, unless can rely on a combination of the LogonId, the file's creation time and the system boot time: If the file was created before the system booted then you know it wasn't the current session that created the file, otherwise you can rely on the value of LogonId to make this distinction. There's one caveat: the file's creation time can be adjusted by users, so a lot depends on your circumstances (does your environment allow for this, etc).

Comment: You should be able to get the LogonId LUID by calling OpenProcessToken (or OpenThreadToken if you're doing LogonUser and Impersonate) then GetTokenInformation with TokenStatistics and use the AuthenticationId field of the resulting structure.